# Print folder structure in C# console application

Tags: c#, console, directory-structure, spectre.console

I want to make a FileSystem reader in C#.
I want to print the folder structure of given path.

The information of the files and directories are getting stored in a database.
The models in use:
File:

```
    internal class File
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileID { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public float FileSize { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DirectoryID")]
        public int DirectoryID { get; set; }

        public Directory Directory { get; set; }
    }
```

Directories:

```
    internal class Directory
    {
        [Key]
        public int DirectoryID { get; set; }

        public string DirectoryName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string DirectoryPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public float DirectorySize { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        public List<File> Files { get; set; } = new();
    }
```

I want to display it like this:

[image: Found this on the internet but I don't know how to do it...]

Does anybody have an idea how to print it like that?

I tried using Spectre.Console but I couldn't get the hang of it...

Comment: Side note: Your current model doesn't make it easy to create nesting directories. There's no parent or child directory in your directory class - this can only be inferred from the value of `DirectoryPath`.

Comment: Also, why are FileSize and DirectorySize floats? Hint: FileInfo.Length is a long.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I updated my models like the other mentions.

File:

```
public class FileModel
{
    [Key]
    public int FileModelID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long FileSize { get; set; }

    public FolderModel Folder { get; set; }
}
```

Folder:

```
public class FolderModel
{
    [Key]
    public int FolderModelID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FolderName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long FolderSize { get; set; }


    public List<FolderModel> SubFolders { get; set; } = new();

    public List<FileModel> Files { get; set; } = new();
}
```

To get the folder structure and the folder size I programmed this method:

```
    public FolderModel GetFolderStructure(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        FolderModel folder = new()
        {
            FolderName = directory.Name,
            CreationDate = directory.CreationTime,
            FolderPath = path,
            FolderSize = 0
        };

        folder.FolderSize = SearchFolder(folder);
        return folder;
    }
```

And the SearchFolder-method to make it recursive:

```
private long SearchFolder(FolderModel parentFolder)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(parentFolder.FolderPath);

        long totalSize = 0;

        
        foreach(var fileInfo in directory.GetFiles())
        {
            FileModel file = new()
            {
                FileName = fileInfo.Name,
                FilePath = fileInfo.FullName,
                FileSize = fileInfo.Length,
                CreationDate = fileInfo.CreationTime
            };

            totalSize = totalSize + fileInfo.Length;

            parentFolder.Files.Add(file);
        }

        foreach (var directoryInfo in directory.GetDirectories())
        {
            FolderModel folder = new()
            {
                FolderName = directoryInfo.Name,
                FolderPath = directoryInfo.FullName,
                CreationDate = directoryInfo.CreationTime,
                FolderSize = 0
            };

            parentFolder.SubFolders.Add(folder);

            folder.FolderSize = SearchFolder(folder);

            totalSize = totalSize + folder.FolderSize;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }
```

And with the Spectre.Console Nuget-Package you can print the folder structure as a tree.

```
private static void DrawTree(FolderModel rootFolder)
{
    Tree tree = new Tree(rootFolder.FolderName);

    AddNode(rootFolder, tree);

    AnsiConsole.Write(tree);
}

private static void AddNode(FolderModel folder, IHasTreeNodes node)
{
    foreach (FileModel file in folder.Files)
    {
        node.AddNode(file.FileName);
    }

    foreach (FolderModel subFolder in folder.SubFolders)
    {
        TreeNode n = node.AddNode(subFolder.FolderName);

        AddNode(subFolder, n);
    }
}
```

With the code I managed to get a tree that looks like the one from my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
tree
```

```
git ls-tree [-d] [-r] [-t] [-l] [-z]
        [--name-only] [--name-status] [--object-only] [--full-name] [--full-tree] [--abbrev[=<n>]] [--format=<format>]
        <tree-ish> [<path>…​]
```

open terminal and type tree how we can get folder structre
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree